# getting error as ERROR: error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.40/info: dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.31.0.2:53: no such host

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using aws runner for running my CI job
Below is my CI code

```
variables:
  APP_NAME: firefox
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

publish-firefox:
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  tags:
    - aws-runner
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
  script:
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PROD
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PROD/$APP_NAME:"$FIREFOX_IMAGE_TAG" --build-arg FIREFOX_VERSION="$FIREFOX_VERSION" --build-arg GECKODRIVER_VERSION="$GECKODRIVER_VERSION" .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PROD/$APP_NAME:"$FIREFOX_IMAGE_TAG"
```

While getting login to ecr, its throwing an error called

ERROR: error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.40/info: dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.21.0.2:53: no such host.

I've tried multiple solutions like adding docker sock in runner config file, setting --privilege= true, used docker:stable, docker:latest, used service flag with docker:dind, docker:18.09-dind etc but had no luck.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure if you are using your own runner then docker-machine needs to be installed, if that does not work then

change the image name in the yaml file

```
publish-firefox:
  image: 
    name: docker:stable
    entrypoint: [""]
```

If this does not solve the issue just check docker is running or not on the runner
Also check that your are using proper profile for login to ECR

```
- aws configure --profile <profile-name> set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- aws configure --profile <profile-name> set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- PASSWORD=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --profile <profile-name>)
- docker login -u AWS -p $PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're likely experiencing (assuming that you've properly exposed the socket for DIND to work on your `aws-runner`) is that you need an alias for the DIND service, otherwise the DNS won't resolve properly in your linked container:

```
publish-firefox:
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  tags:
    - aws-runner
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: docker
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
  script:
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PROD
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PROD/$APP_NAME:"$FIREFOX_IMAGE_TAG" --build-arg FIREFOX_VERSION="$FIREFOX_VERSION" --build-arg GECKODRIVER_VERSION="$GECKODRIVER_VERSION" .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PROD/$APP_NAME:"$FIREFOX_IMAGE_TAG"
```

note the `name` and `alias` tags in your services in the above example.

Comment: I've tried this too, It wont work for me

Comment: There is likely some issue with your aws-runner then and how the socket is exposed, which could result in DIND never starting. To test the above code and ensure it worked, I created a clean project in GitLab and pasted my suggestion (minus the tag, and just pulling an alpine docker image) and it worked without issue.

Comment: One thing you could potentially do as a workaround if you don't want to go digging for what's wrong with the ec2 instance setup: take a look at kaniko, which is explicitly meant for building docker images within other docker images, and provides an ECR helping for publishing images. This will allow you to completely ignore DIND, as it doesn't need access to the docker daemon.